# How to create a Yarn request token when sending a request to Yarn Resource Manager

Tags: hadoop-yarn

I am trying to create an Unmanaged ApplicationMaster and having issues with creating AMRMtokens right. I peeked into the TestAMRMtokens.java test cases and here is what I have come up with. (This is scala code)

```
def getNextAttemptid() : ApplicationAttemptId = {
    val t = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()
    ConverterUtils.toApplicationAttemptId(ConverterUtils.APPLICATION_ATTEMPT_PREFIX + "_" + t.toString() + "_0001" + "_0001")
}

appAttemptId = getNextAttemptid()

UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(yarnConf)
val ugi = UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser()
val tokenIdentifier = new AMRMTokenIdentifier(appAttemptId)
val secretManager = new AMRMTokenSecretManager(yarnConf)
val token: Token[_ <: TokenIdentifier] = new Token[AMRMTokenIdentifier](tokenIdentifier, secretManager)
ugi.addToken(token)

amClient = AMRMClient.createAMRMClient()
amClient.init(yarnConf)
amClient.start()
val appMasterResponse = amClient.registerApplicationMaster("localhost", 0, "")
```

Yarn does not like this request and says:

**2014-01-27 10:47:10,938 WARN SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth failed for 127.0.0.1:63085:null (DIGEST-MD5: IO error acquiring password)
2014-01-27 10:47:10,938 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8030: readAndProcess from client 127.0.0.1 threw exception [org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken: Password not found for 
ApplicationAttempt appattempt_1390848430314_0001_000001]**

I am sure I am doing something wrong. Is there documentation or example code that shows how to create the tokens right? Do I have to setup these users somewhere in Yarn/Hadoop configuration.

Configuration:

1. hadoop 2.2.0
2. All services are listening on localhost interface Just
   using out of the box configuration. No special changes.